# How can I create a correct seedhash in ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, yellow-paper

In the ethereum yellowpaper, about the creation of seedhash, I found that, when height is less 30000, the seedhash S = keccak256({0}32), description is:

> Seed hash. The seed hash is different for every epoch. For the first epoch it is the Keccak-256 hash of a series of 32 bytes of zeros. For every other epoch it is always the Keccak-256 hash of the previous seed hash.

but, in the python code, like this:

```
 def get_seedhash(block):
     s = '\x00' * 32
     for i in range(block.number // EPOCH_LENGTH):
         s = serialize_hash(sha3_256(s))
     return s
```

And in go-ethereum, the code is:

```
func seedHash(block uint64) []byte {
    seed := make([]byte, 32)
    if block < epochLength {
        return seed
    }
    keccak256 := makeHasher(sha3.NewKeccak256())
    for i := 0; i < int(block/epochLength); i++ {
        keccak256(seed, seed)
    }
    return seed
}
```

So, it seems that some different between the yellow paper and code. In the code, when height is less 30000, the seedHash return {0}32.
I'm in a puzzle in this problem.
Thank you for anyone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends what you mean by "correct". As long as the seedhash for each epoch (i.e. each 30,000 blocks mined) is different, I don't think it actually matters how the hash is generated.

Looking more closely at the Geth code, [`seedHash()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/4b5e79728862da8ee7598e8d0f128b2d1543e245/consensus/ethash/algorithm.go#L67) returns a seed which is then fed into [`generateCache()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/4b5e79728862da8ee7598e8d0f128b2d1543e245/consensus/ethash/algorithm.go#L85). In `generateCache()` the seed is hashed using `keccak512()` before it is used. So for the first epoch, although the `seedHash()` function doesn't call `keccak256()` (at least for Geth), the seed of `{0}32` *is* hashed before use. (There may also be further complexities further down the call chain... )

Comment: Actually, the python and go-ethereum have the same result.

Comment: You're correct - the floor division in the loop prevents it being entered, obviously :-) (It's early here... ) I'll edit my answer so it's not misleading. I think the rest of the answer still stands, i.e. we're never actually using `0` as a seed as it later gets hashed anyway. It just doesn't quite agree with the Yellow Paper (`keccak512`, done in the next function vs. `keccak256` in `seedHash()`).

Comment: (Other people closer to the code may know if there's a reason for this disagreement - I don't.)

Comment: But, this disagreement is very strange.